# ¿Existe una función en php que dada una fecha y hora de un país me devuelva la fecha y hora equivalente en otro país?

Tags: php

Tengo una serie de eventos guardados en db con el uso horario de España, y lo que quiero es mostrar la hora y el dia adecuados en los que dicho evento paso segun el pais del usuario.

Ejemplo:
Una persona en España guarda un comentario a la 1:01 del 1 de enero.
Otra persona en Portugal consulta la fecha del comentario y ve que el comentario se realizó a las 12:01 del 31 de diciembre.

Answer (score 1):

Si, se puede :

```php
$userTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$gmtTimezone = new DateTimeZone('GMT');
$myDateTime = new DateTime('2016-03-21 13:14', $gmtTimezone);
$offset = $userTimezone->getOffset($myDateTime);
$myInterval=DateInterval::createFromDateString((string)$offset . 'seconds');
$myDateTime->add($myInterval);
$result = $myDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
Echo $result;
```

fuente: https://blog.serverdensity.com/handling-timezone-conversion-with-php-datetime/